# Why is CUDA with pytorch freezing and work worse than cpu on my device? Is this a configuration issue or a hardware issue?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision, cudnn

I am trying to retrain the last layer of ResNet18 but running into problems using CUDA. I am not hearing the GPU and in Task Manager GPU usage is minimal when running with CUDA. I increased the tensors per image to 5 which I was expecting to impact performance but not to this extent. It ran overnight and still did not get past the first epoch.

I am loosely following the transfer learning tutorial here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#load-data .

Additional info: 11 image classes, most classes have 3000 images, some have a few hundred images.

I checked driver and CUDA compatibility and it seems like 12.1 is compatible with my current driver version. compute capability 7.5 which is also within range. I think there may be some kind of issue with how I am using Torch but not sure what it may be.

[nivida-smi GTX-1650](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV7zp.png)

I don't think CUDA/my GPU is working at all since I would try to visualize the images and it would completely freeze.

Code:

To import and preprocess the data into tensors

```
def stack_tensor(crops):
    return torch.stack([transforms.ToTensor()(crop) for crop in crops])

def normalize_tensor(crops):
    return torch.stack([transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])(crop) for crop in crops])

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(512),
        transforms.FiveCrop(224),
        transforms.Lambda(stack_tensor),
        transforms.Lambda(normalize_tensor)
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(512),
        transforms.FiveCrop(224),
        transforms.Lambda(stack_tensor),
        transforms.Lambda(normalize_tensor)
    ]),
}

data_dir = ''
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

To train the model

```
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
    since = time.time()

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs - 1}')
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

            print(f'{phase} Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f} Acc: {epoch_acc:.4f}')

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

        print()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print(f'Training complete in {time_elapsed // 60:.0f}m {time_elapsed % 60:.0f}s')
    print(f'Best val Acc: {best_acc:4f}')

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model
```

To call the training model. I had pretrained on a dataset using CPU before I managed to get CUDA working, so was continuing to train with those starting weights.

```
# Create new model
model_ft = models.resnet18(weights=ResNet18_Weights.DEFAULT)

# Load existing model
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 11)
model_ft.load_state_dict(torch.load("initialmodel"))

# num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
# Here the size of each output sample is set to 2.
# Alternatively, it can be generalized to nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_names)).
# model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 11)

model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Observe that all parameters are being optimized
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

model_ft = train_model(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=7)
```

Comment: First check the device varaible, if it shows cuda or cpu. Second increase the batch size, and watch gpu usage, for example to 512.